# Pivot from long to wide using dplyr pivot_wider?

Tags: r, dplyr, format, pivot, reshape

I have repeated measurements on glucose in a long format that looks as follows:

```
mydata <- 
  structure(list(
    ID = c(4, 12, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 43, 50, 51, 52, 61, 67, 81, 82, 83, 88, 93, 93, 94, 100, 103, 105, 106, 107, 115, 117, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 132, 136, 157, 173, 180, 194, 196, 230, 244, 245, 269, 288, 304, 316, 318, 334, 338, 338, 367, 378, 380), 
    date = structure(c(15330, 15476, 17641, 17664, 17664, 17670, 17673, 18696, 18194, 16036, 16428, 16210, 16211, 17667, 16329, 17961, 18535, 16834, 18088, 18571, 16449, 18213, 18003, 17976, 16862, 17842, 18019, 17339, 18513, 18629, 18699, 18700, 18700, 18423, 17184, 17487, 16736, 18780, 16876, 16895, 17163, 17443, 18291, 18493, 18213, 17947, 18452, 17919, 18129, 18152, 18794, 18507, 18640, 18654), 
                     class = "Date"), 
    name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                     .Label = "gluc", 
                     class = "factor"), 
    value = c(5.6, 5.5, 6.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.4, 4.3, 4.7, 5.1, 4.3, 5.2, 5.1, 5.8, 10, 5.2, 8.7, 4.5, 6.1, 4.6, 6, 5.8, 5.9, 5.5, 5.3, 5.9, 10.1, 6.4, 21.2, 5.1, 5.9, 7.4, NA, 8, 9.5, 4.6, 7, 8.1, 5.5, 7, 5, 6.2, 4.9, 4.8, 8.3, 6, 5.5, 6.8, 6.1, 4.8, 6.3, 5.7, 6.2, 13.7)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -54L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


head(mydata)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
     ID date       name  value
  <dbl> <date>     <fct> <dbl>
1     4 2011-12-22 gluc    5.6
2    12 2012-05-16 gluc    5.5
3    24 2018-04-20 gluc    6.5
4    24 2018-05-13 gluc    7.6
5    24 2018-05-13 gluc    7.7
6    24 2018-05-19 gluc    7.8
```

I am trying to convert this to a wideformat. I've tried:

```
# First try
lab_gluc_wide <- 
  pivot_wider(
    data=mydata, 
    names_from=name, 
    values_from=value, 
    id_cols=c(ID, date))

# Second try
lab_gluc_wide <- 
  pivot_wider(
    data=mydata, 
    names_from=name, 
    values_from=c(value, date), 
    id_cols=ID)
```

But both produce the warning messages

```
1: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 
2: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

What I am looking for is one row per patient, with multiple columns per each glucose measurement/date.

Comment: Your are using the `pivot_wider` function to pivot to long format? YOu probably want to use `pivot_longer`! BUt your data actually looks like long format already, so are you triying to pivot wider after all? Also your "name" column just has one value - "gluc", so what's the point of reshaping in the first place? Please clarify what's your problem. I guess you want to pivot_wider to get one row per ID?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want! One row per ID, multiple columsn per measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that your IDs also are on unique days, so if you reshape your data to wide format, you would also need to reshape your date column or get rid of it. In my example, I deleted the date column.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ID_ID = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, ID_ID),
              id_cols = c(ID))
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 43 x 7
      ID gluc_1 gluc_2 gluc_3 gluc_4 gluc_5 gluc_6
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     4    5.6   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 2    12    5.5   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 3    24    6.5    7.6    7.7    7.8    7.4     NA
 4    43    4.3   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 5    50    4.7   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 6    51    5.1   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 7    52    4.3   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 8    61    5.2   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
 9    67    5.1   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
10    81    5.8   NA     NA     NA     NA       NA
# ... with 33 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful and preetty much what I need.